# Sorting an NSMutableArray by criteria

Tags: swift, sorting, nsmutablearray

I want to sort the NSMutableArray by date order:

```
var currentReminders: NSMutableArray
```

This array stores reminder objects like this:

```
class Reminders: NSObject {

    var title: String?
    var dueDate = NSDate()

    init(...) {...}
}
```

I want to sort the `currentReminder` in ascending order of date (which one having the most recent `dueDate` will stand above)

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `NSSortDescriptor` object and sort the array with it:

```
var dateDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dueDate", ascending: true)
var sortedArray = currentReminders.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([dateDescriptor])
```

The new `sortedArray` will contain objects ordered by `dueDate`.

Also, I would suggest using native Swift objects like `Array<T>` without `NSObject`subclasses. That would make sorting and data handling much easier.